# Can't pass null to java recursive search

Tags: java, search, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to write a simple recursive method to see if a binary search tree contains a value. This is what I initially came up with:

```
static boolean doesContainData(Node root, int data){
    if (root.data == data){
        return true;
    }

    if (root == null){
        return false;
    }

    if (data > root.data){
        return doesContainData(root.right, data);
    }

    else if(data < root.data){
        return doesContainData(root.left, data);
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, it appears that for cases where the BST doesn't contain the node with data, it throws me a NullPointerException. After some testing, I realized that when I changed the function to this, it worked:

```
static boolean doesContainData(Node root, int data){
    if (root.data == data){
        return true;
    }

    if (root == null){
        return false;
    }

    if (data > root.data){
        if (root.right == null){
            return false;
        }
        return doesContainData(root.right, data);
    } 

    else if(data < root.data){
        if (root.left == null){
            return false;
        }
        return doesContainData(root.left, data);
    }
    return false;  
}
```

I'm not quite sure why the latter works and the former doesn't. In the latter, I'm checking to see if the left/right nodes are null, but I don't see how this is different than the original method. In the first method, I just called the recursive method again, which should end up checking the node in the base case.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `if (root == null){` will never be true because the use of `root.data` would throw a NullPointerException before.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you call doesContainData(root.right, data) or doesContainData(root.left, data), your method doesContainData gets called.

In this case if root.left or root.right is null, when you call the following method,

```
if (root.data == data){
    return true;
}
```

before root.data == data being checked, root.data will throw a NullPointerException, because this doesn't exist.

However your later approach will check, root.left or root.right is null before calling doesContainData method. If it is null, your method will return false and terminates. Therefore initial issue never occurs.